# Why the results differs from headless webdriver to heded webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

just try to run te next code, because I'm having troubles trying to retrive the elements' src when run in headless mode

`tiendas = ["exito", "carulla", "carulla-fresh","exito-express"]`

`lista = []`

`for j,i in  enumerate(tiendas[:1]):`

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
#options.add_argument("--headless")
#options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
#options.add_argument('window-size=1051x806')
#options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# options.use_chromium = True
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get(f"https://www.rappi.com.co/tiendas/{i}/")

try:
    localizacion = driver.find_element_by_id('rappi-address-input')
    localizacion.click()
    localizacion.send_keys("Bogotá")
    localizacion.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    localizacion.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    boton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='primary-button-filled continue-button']")
    boton.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    localizacion_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"]')
    
    localizacion_1.send_keys("Calle 127 # 11 - 30 Bogotá")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="result-description"]').click()
    
except:
    next

time.sleep(3)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='search-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid']")
search.click()
search.send_keys("maní")
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='iconf-search']")
button.click()

time.sleep(2)

#WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@class='ng-lazyloaded']")))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

len(soup.find_all("img",{"class":"ng-lazyloading"}))
```

when you run the code headed you obtain a len of **30** but if you run the code headless you obtain a len of **14**

Anybody knows why on earth this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

headless browser sends useragent that indicates that the agent is running in headless mode. Some websites detects this and serves a different page to these agents . To avoid this use

```
chromeoption.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
 browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeoption )
```

Also the windows size of headless will be different than the actual resolution:

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1080")
```

Set the actual window size as your screen using above argument

### Update

Preferrence are not supported in headless mode

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

if you take screenshot of the page you can see that images get loaded , when your remove preferrence the count again changes

TO take screenshot:

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("hi.png")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

This will take screenshot as hi.png in current directory

Comment: Not working, I'm gonna edit the question to show the output

Comment: @AlexisAG https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

Comment: Preferrence are not supporteed for headless

Comment: although preferrences are not supported, nothing change if I disable them, and its quite strange that some src attributes are extracted and some others no.